# Not allowing contradiction is an axiom?

Tags: logic

When proving $p$ is true by contradiction, we suppose $p$ is false and then draw a contradiction. So $p$ is true.

I don't understand why the contradiction implies $p$ is true.

Comment: This is known as the [Law of the Excluded Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle).

Comment: Rather than an axiom, the law of excluded middle is a [law of logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_logic). I would not say that laws of logic are axioms of mathematics. Instead they are, perhaps, axioms of formal reasoning.

Comment: See [Proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction).

It is one of the building blocks of human reasoning, *quite* universally accepted: if we suppose that a statement $p$ holds and - by way of valid logical steps - we derive form it a *contradiction*, we have to reject our initial assumption.

The rule is strictly linked with the definition of [logical consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence) itself:

> a *conclusion* of an argument is a logical consequence of a set of *assumptions* if it is not possible that all the assumptions are TRUE and the conclusion is FALSE.

But a contradiction is always FALSE; thus, if we have derived it in a logical correct way from an assumption $p$, we have only two possibilities: either

*(i)* the logical argument used in the proof is not correct, or

*(ii)* the assumption must be FALSE.

---

What happens with the case of $p$ FALSE ?

In this case we have the interplay of Proof by contradiction with another principle (also this principle is *quite* universally accepted): the [Law of Excluded Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle):

> assuming the falsity of $p$ amounts to say that its negation: $\lnot p$ is TRUE.

---

---

There are objections to the previous approach; see [Intuitionsim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Mathematical_constructivism).

Comment: Very impressive expression, "one of the building blocks of human reasoning". I am wondering who build those blocks.

Comment: @user682705 - see [Aristotle's Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/) and [Aristotle on Non-contradiction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-noncontradiction/) and [Contradiction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/contradiction/)

Comment: Very useful : Walter Carnielli & Jacek Malinowski (editors), [Contradictions, from Consistency to Inconsistency (Springer, 2018)](https://books.google.it/books?id=xIJyDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: As well as Can Başkent & Thomas Macaulay Ferguson (editors), [Graham Priest : On Dialetheism And Paraconsistency (2019, Springer)](https://books.google.it/books?id=PZPHDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) and Jan Wolenski, [Semantics And Truth (2019, Springer)](https://books.google.it/books?id=L5PHDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference!